# EditText getting defocused on refresing recyclerview

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

### EditText in recyclerview

I am using a `Recyclerview` to show a list of `EditText`.

**My requirement** is whenever I click on `EditText` it should open a numeric keypad and the item should get highlighted as it is getting selected.

**My Code does the following:**
My fragment is the listener of the item clicked.
Whenever item gets clicked it calls the listener method in the fragment, that methods updates the selected item and it refreshes the adapter so that the selected item gets highlighted.

**Listener method in fragment:**

```
@Override
public void itemClicked(int position) {
    for (MyClass myObject : myObjectList) {
        myObject.isSelected = false;
    }
    myObjectList[position].isSelected = true;
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**In my adapter:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
if(myObjectList[position].isSelected){
    // highlight this item
   }else{
   // do not highlight this item
   }
}
```

This works totally fine. But I want to do same whenever `EditText` in the item of recyclerview gets clicked.

**The problem is:**
first of all what kind of listener should I use for EditText click and why?
I used **OnFocusChangedListener**, There I called my listener method in fragment which selects proper position, but when it refreshes the adapter it defocuses my clicked EditText(defocuses means it removes cursor from clicked edittext) and one more thing it changes the numeric keypad into normal keypad.

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    if (clickListener != null) {
                       clickListener.itemClicked(getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**The problem is obvious according to my code but I am not getting the trick  to solve it.**
**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**